# FCM using push notification ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

**FCM using push notification ionic 4[image]**

i had attach my error log too,

i installed [https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQNsq.png)

i am using ionic cli---4.12.0

```
I am trying to send push notification on my device with the help of FCM
```

and ionic 4. But I'm unable to get token,. I'm getting device token for iOS 
and I've import **app.module.ts**,**app.component.ts** aslo ,
i have  try to store token in local storage but im getting null value
is there i missing??

```
 initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
  this.splashScreen.hide();
  this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('marketing');


  //Receving
  this.fcm.getToken().then((token) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }, (err) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
  });


  this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log("Data :", data);
    if (data.wasTapped) {
      console.log("Received in background " + JSON.stringify(data));
      alert("Received in background " + JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {
      console.log("Received in foreground" + JSON.stringify(data));
      alert("Received in foreground" + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
  //Updating
  this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe((token) => {

    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    console.log(token);
    alert('refresh token: ' + token);
  });

  this.fcm.unsubscribeFromTopic('marketing');

});
```

}

Comment: Are you debugging on real device? Plugins will not work in Browsers. you have to have Real Device to get Token.

Comment: thnx,i try real device worked fine,,,,